# in maven, an extension packaging type throws "unknown packaging error" if the plugin is declared inside an activation profile that is not activated

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

For instance, the NAR plugin defines a new packaging type called "nar".

Works fine in a simple case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>blah</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
    <artifactId>blahblab</artifactId>

    <packaging>nar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But if you nest that build into an activation profile **that does not get activated**, such as running this pom on linux:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>blah</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
    <artifactId>blahblab</artifactId>

    <packaging>nar</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <!-- won't get activated on linux -->
        <profile>
            <id>some-exotic-os-only</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Mac OS</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**Maven no longer knows what nar means and chokes.**

```
#  mvn -U help:active-profiles
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project blah:blahblab:1 (/tmp/test/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: nar @ line 13, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Run it on the mac, and it's fine.  But that kind of defeats the point of profiles...  I want this to do nothing on all os's except on mac.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your concerns.

1. Define your packaging.  This need not happen in a profile; if it does, it must be an activeByDefault profile.
2. Restrict your project based on your requirements.

   - If you want to fail the build, the [enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) will do this for you.
   - If you want to skip building the nar, then you can use your default profile to configure the nar plugin with the `skipNar` configuration item.  In you mac profile, create a new configuration without the `skipNar` configuration item.

---

This snippet (pulled from the [enforce plugin's website](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html), and modified a little) should work for the fail-the-build option.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-versions</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireOS>
              <family>mac</family>
            </requireOS>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

---

For the skipNar option, some variation on this may suit you.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>noBuildNar</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
         <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <skipNar/>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>buildNar</id>
    <activation>
      <family>mac</family>
    </activation>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
         <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: separating concerns is a good point.  I will split my checks into different profiles.  The problem is the enforcer plugin fails the build if whatever rules don't pass.  I don't want this.  I just want it to skip this project and move on to the next project.  That's what profiles SHOULD be doing, but as you point out, the packaging plugin must be active or else maven fails.

Comment: yup, the skip works.  I created a variable in the profile section, then use the value of that in the skip tag.  Thanks.  (annoying stackverflow won't let me award the bounty for 5 more hours.  weird)